# Testing means and proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I've worked with survey researchers, and we used to collect a lot of categorical data. So for significance testing of a 5 point scale, we would do something like recode the original variable into a binary variable where 4/5=1 and 1/2/3=0.

Then we would use a Z test of means of the binary variable and use that proportion to test for significant differences.

I guess my question is, why not use the test of proportions? Would the two yield the same results? In other words, can I take any categorical variable and recode it to 0/1 variable and use a mean test, or conversely use a proportion test?

Why do two different tests exist anyways? Does the means test exist to accommodate truly continuous data?

Comment: The proportions test would probably be more powerful, but the z-test is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

To your general question about the difference between the test of means and the test of proportions the answer comes into the variance (and therefore the standard deviation) of the estimator.

For means, we either take the variance as given, or we compute it from the sample using the estimator
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$$
and for proportions we use the estimator 
$$n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$$
where $\hat{p}$ is the sample estiamtor of the proportion of successes. Okay so we see that these are two different estimators.

Now for your original problem, neither of these estimators are really appropriate for categorical analysis. The most basic test is that of the **chi-squared** significance test. You could also look at other non-parametric tests.

Comment: Example: scale of 1 to 5 from two time periods, I want to see if the proportion of 4s and 5s is significantly different across the two time periods. I'd have to use a chi-squared test, or could I just compute the % falling into those two levels and do a proportions test?

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't read that intro very carefully, yes you can use the Z-test in this case (i.e. the proportions-test) because we only have two outcomes (1,2,3 vs 4,5)  and for large sample sizes binomial -> normal